# How to do pagination without using external library like pagelist.mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, pagination

I want to make a pagination in my project and i don't want to use Pagelist.mvc in the project. So do i have any other way to do it in mvc4?

Comment: have a try on **IPagedList**.

Comment: You would need to write your own paging, not hard just pull one page of data at a time with your data query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use webgrid. Using webgrid you can achieve pagination

```
@model IEnumerable<ItemMaster>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Item Details";
    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model,rowsPerPage:5);
}
<h2>Item Details</h2>
@grid.GetHtml()
```